# Problem with Vertex Coordinates

Tags: python

I'm using Blender 2.74 and trying to make this part of my code work:

```
import bpy
from math import *

me = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(radius = 0.5, depth = 1)

for v in me.verts:
    v.co[2] =v.co[2]+0.5
```

But appear the folow error:'set' object has no attribute 'verts'.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print out the content of `me` in the console, you can see that it does not contain the cylinder's mesh data:

```
>>> me
{'FINISHED'}
```

The `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add` operator, like most operators in Blender, returns its exit status (in our case {'FINISHED'} - signalling success) rather then the result of whatever it did.

If you want to access the vertices, you can do this through `bpy.context.object.data.vertices`, since after you add a cylinder primitive, it becomes the active object (context.object):

```
import bpy
from math import *

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(radius = 0.5, depth = 1)
me = bpy.context.object.data

for v in me.vertices:
    v.co[2] =v.co[2]+0.5
```

A few other things worth noting:

1. The vertex collection in the mesh object's data is called *vertices* (For instance: `context.object.data.vertices`) not *verts*. The [bmesh](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_release/bmesh.html) module does call the vertex collection verts, which is probably why this confused you.
2. It's considered bad practice to import everything from a module, unless you're actually going to use everything you imported (`from math import *`). You should only import whatever function you intend to use. For instance:

   ```
   from math import degrees, radians
   ```
3. Small tip regarding debugging in blender (and in general):
   The error message you got gave you a nice lead for debugging. It says that whatever it is you're trying to use `.verts` with doesn't really have any attribute called 'verts'. The next logical thing is to check what the heck is inside the `me` variable by printing it, to see why it has no verts. This would have showed that `me` is indeed a set, not a mesh data object, which whould have indicated that the `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add` operator returns an exit status, and not the cylinder's data.
4. [EDIT] And another late one. To get a shorter and more readable version of your scaling action, you can replace this:

   ```
   v.co[2] =v.co[2]+0.5
   ```

   With this:

   ```
   v.co.z += 0.5
   ```

Comment: Nice explanation @TLousky! The tips will help me a lot! Thanks ! :)

Comment: No problem @Jimmy, added another small tip for good measure ;-)